# Convert char to String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, console, char

**Read it, Before it gets marked as duplicate**
*Sorry! I couldn't come up with a better description of the question*

Anyways, I was making a simple program which reverses the given word (e.g 'word' to 'drow'). I was trying to convert the String into char array first and then printing each character backwards in the console using for loop. However, I need to save the value in a String now that I can't seem to figure out.
This is the code here:

```
 var answer = document.getElementById("ta").value;
 var arr = answer.split("");
      for(i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--) { //minus 1 because index starts at 0
           str = arr[i];
           console.log(str); //it works but displays each character individually
           }
```

I just want all the characters in a String. Please help! Brevity in the answer would be appreciated

Comment: You can reverse a string using `str.split('').reverse().join('')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript unlike other oops, provide an inherited reverse function that reverses **array**. So one answer to this whould be:

```
let arr = answer.split("") //note this creates an array with each char as element of array
arr = arr.reverse(); //this reverses the array
let string = arr.join(""); //this joins the array into a single string
```

Another method would be the one you are trying to do, create your own reverse function. You are doing it all right but just missing a step, that is to join the array, you are simply printing each letter of the array and thats the property of console.log that each console.log prints to a new line. That explains why you are getting it all in new line.

```
var answer = document.getElementById("ta").value;
 var arr = answer.split("");
var str ="";
      for(i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--) { //minus 1 because index starts at 0
           str =str +  arr[i];
           }
console.log(str); //it should be outside the loop and print string once it has been formed
```

P.S:I have given as much detail I can on this to get you started but this is a very basic question and doesnt deserve to be here, you should follow some basic concepts of js on mdn or w3schools. Plus google your problems before turning to stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks and agreed! I just started learning vanilla JavaScript from w3schools. I'd the blueprints of this program from a JavaFX application I made in Java which filters 'Palindromes' from the dictionary and also wasn't familiar with the inherited functions in JS. So, I tried to code it the same way, maybe that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put all the characters in str you can try this way:

```
str= str+arr[i]
```

or try this way:

```
var str = "";
arr.forEach(element => {str= str+element});
 console.log(str)
```